# 英語が残っている: 削除された質問にアクセスした際の Here are some similar questions that might be relevant:

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1691

> Here are some similar questions that might be relevant:
>
> Try a Google 検索

Transifexで探したのですが見つからないので、一旦こちらに書いておきます。

訳の案としては、`類似の質問:`とか`お探しの質問はこちらでしょうか:`とか・・・。

Comment: Transifexに入るようにします。

Answer (score 1):

ニュアンス的に「この質問は削除されましたが、似たような質問もあります：」だと思います。

とりあえず、英語よりなんでもいいので、自分が一番好きな翻訳にしてもいいと思います。あとで違和感があれば、このメタ投稿へ見れば、自分の責任になります！

Comment: あ、その訳いいですね！Transifex上にない気がするのですが、どこかにありますでしょうか？